# Serving pre-roll , mid - roll and post - roll ads using dfp without IMA sdk

Tags: google-dfp, ads, vast, video-ads

I am trying to integrate advertising to non - standard platforms, for which IMA sdk is not supported. Assuming I am using VAST with google Double Click for Publishers, is it too much of work to write my own sdk / VAST parser to display the ads ? Is is sane to write a VAST parser and play ads by configuring the platform specific video player to play the ads , and fire the required events using HTTP get or post requests to the DFP ? is the effort equivalent to writing a huge library altogether or just a small plug - in ?

Answer (score 0):

For which platform(s) are you trying to use IMA?  If the native SDKs (Android and iOS) don't work on your platform, you can always use the HTML5 SDK *with* [custom playback](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/custom-playback) enabled.  In Custom Playback (see [IMA HTML5 Rendering](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2015/06/ima-html5-rendering.html)), the SDK will intelligently make a decision whether to use one player or two players for ad and content playback.

For example, if you want to serve ads on your Chromecast, while IMA doesn't have a native plugin for Chromecast, you would use the HTML5 SDK with custom playback enabled to allow for a seamless experience.  Custom playback should work across multiple platforms and video players, given you pass your player reference to the SDK.

Comment: roku ,  android apps developed using react - native